# SQL : Better way to re-write this SQL. without using max function

Tags: sql, group-by, databricks, union

SQL:

```
select QID, max(DT), max(city)
from (
  select '1' as QID,  '' as DT, 'NYC' as city
  union
  select '1' as QID, '2023-04-18' as DT, '' as city )
group by QID
```

I am getting expected output (Just 1 row) in above sql. Is there better way to re-write this sql, without using max function.

Output:

| QID | max(DT) | max(city) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-04-18 | NYC |

Comment: If there were more than one `QID` present, would you also expect more than one record in the output?

Comment: yes.. idea is to group(or get) the values from each sub-queries for particular QID

Comment: Bear in mind, SQL is a *declarative* language. You tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. That means that if you have two queries that *logically* request the same result, the query optimizer should produce the *same plan*, whether or not either of them happens to spell part of it as `MAX()` and the other does not.

Comment: Please post a complete sample data and desired output that covers more interesting cases with more rows per `qid` with different values in *other* columns between rows. It's hard to answer your current question because you may have a lot of ways to combine three scalars into a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample data looks like:

[image]

You can solve the query using two joins, but using the aggregation is more efficient:

```
 select QID, max(DT), max(city) 
 from 
 ( 
        select '1' as QID, '' 
           as DT, 'NYC' as city 
       union 
       select '1' as QID, '2023-04-18' as DT, '' as city 
) DS
group by QID
;

WITH DS  AS  
 ( 
        select '1' as QID, '' 
           as DT, 'NYC' as city 
       union 
       select '1' as QID, '2023-04-18' as DT, '' as city 
)
SELECT *
FROM DS DS1
INNER JOIN DS DS2
    ON DS1.QID = DS2.QID
WHERE DS1.DT <> ''
    AND DS2.City <> ''
```

[image]

---

The above example is run on SQL Server, but basically you should be able to execute it on most of the databases. The idea is that reading the data once, would be faster then reading it twice (using joins) as more IO will be needed.

Comment: Who says the OP is using SQL Server?

Comment: It should also be noted that this will work for exactly one row with not empty `DT` and exactly one row with not empty `city`. If one of the rows is missing - you'll don't get anything, and if there multiple of such rows - you'll get multiplied number of rows.